# Material-UI Pickers – Make empty date (onblur) trigger error

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Problem: I'm using [material-ui-pickers](https://next.material-ui-pickers.dev) and cannot figure out how to trigger/initiate an error when user removes focus / onBlur and date field is empty.

I've tried to alter the colors of text and underline to error color(red), however the screen readers / a11y will not register the error. This means that it must trigger the "internal" error system of date picker.

Comment: Please provide codesandbox for the same so we can see your issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@material-ui-pickers` inherits the props from [Material-UI TextField](https://material-ui.com/api/text-field/) , you will notice that `error` is `boolean`.

In order to create an error message you will need to satisfy two props, `error` and `helperText`.

You did not provide an example but it should be something like that:

```
     <DatePicker
      required
      id="dob"
      label="Date of Birth"
      format={"DD/MM/YYYY"}
      value={this.state.dob}
      className={classes.textField}
      onChange={this.handleDateChange}
      error={!this.state.dob}
      helperText={!this.state.dob && "Error message here"}
    />
```

Comment: Thanks, I had overlooked the boolean property "error" oddly enough.